sublime text 3 choose color as VS does plugin?
want to choose opacity and rgb as in VS code (the square with colors) , does anybody know such plugin ? Again , if you use VS code you have on the left a square that allows you to choose colors more precisly .
i searched on the internet but found nothing.

Did you just try to look into packagecontrol ? For example : https://packagecontrol.io/search/color%20pick
